# Discrete approximation of the Mandelbrot set

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, mandelbrot

I have the following task: draw a discrete approximation of the Mandelbrot set for the quadratic family on the complex plane. I need to do this with a list-based implementation.

I have already created a plot of the Mandelbrot set for the quadratic family on the complex plane, but I couldn't manage to create a discrete approximation. Here's my code in Wolfram Mathematica for the plot of the Mandelbrot set:

```
ArrayPlot[Table[Length@NestWhileList[#^2 + x + I*y &, 0, Abs[#] < 2 &, 1, 100], {y, -1.2, 1.2, 0.002}, {x, -2, 0.5, 0.002}], ColorFunction -> "Pastel", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

How can I create a discrete approximation of the Mandelbrot set?

Comment: You want the [mathematica.se]-specific stackexchange site, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: Isn't any rendering of the Mandelbrot set a discrete approximation by nature, because you evaluate the formula only at specific coordinates? So if you wanted to make it “more discrete” you might increase the step sizes of your loops, but that would be merely a quantitative change, not a qualitative one. If this is not what you want, then you should explain what you mean by discrete in this context.